# Problema con github pages y react-router-dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, github, react-router-dom

tengo una problema con subir mi pagina a github pages, cuando utilizo react-router-dom en App.js y la subo en github pages me aparece en blanco, pero ahora si escribo un `<h1>` y no utilizo react-router-dom y ademas la subo a github pages esta me funciona, osea que llege a la conclusion que el problema es react-router-dom. En el localhost me funciona todo bien con react-router-dom, el problema es cuando lo subo a git hub pages, pero este problema tampoco lo puedo resolver por que no me aparece ningun error en la consola tanto del navegador como el de visual studio code y ya estoy casi un dia tratando de resolver este problema pero no puedo. Dejo el codigo por si ustedes ven un problema que yo no veo
Codigo del package.json:

```
{
  "homepage": "https://fxivan.github.io/ositoservicio",
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.2",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.3",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.2.2",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "predeploy": "npm run build",
    "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gh-pages": "^3.2.3"
  }
}
```

codigo del App.js usando react router dom que me no me funciona:

```
import React from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter, Routes , Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import { Principal } from './component/principal/principal';

function App() {
    return(
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path='/' element={<Principal/>}/>
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    )
}

export default App;
```

Dejo un foto donde donde me funciona dentro del localhost y la otra la pagina subida con git hub pages con la consola(que no me muestra ninguna error):
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Porfavor si alguien me podra decir que esta mal, estoy conciente que la pregunta le falta mostrar error para que ustedes me puedan ayudar, pero es que este problema no me muestra ningun error y nose que mas hacer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola tuve el mismo problema que tu y busque varias formas, pero solo una me funciono. NO estoy seguro como esta organizado tu proyecto pero en mi caso particular tuve que cambiar de BrowserRouter a otro.

App.js

```js
import './App.css';
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from './Pagina/Home';
function App() {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
    </Routes>
  );
}

export default App;
```

index.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import { HashRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import "bootstrap-icons/font/bootstrap-icons.css";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <HashRouter>
        <App />
    </HashRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```